# Facebook Send button to send link to iframe tab

Tags: facebook, facebook-iframe, facebook-apps

It seems that when creating a Send button, Facebook will not let me send a link to the current iFrame tab / app. The link always gets reduced to just the Facebook page.

For example, I want to create a Send button using the following href:
http://www.facebook.com/pages/MyPage/pageid/?sk=app_my_app_id&app_data=My_app_data

But in the send button, the link gets reduced to:
http://www.facebook.com/pages/MyPage/pageid

Any ideas on how to get straight to the correct tab and include the app_data?

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of browsing, looks like you can't include url params on the facebook send button link.  The workaround I've had to use on my project is to encode any parameters as a 'fake' url and rewrite when this when it comes back in to my server:

E.g. instead of this on the FB button link:
http://example.com/index.php?foo=bar

Use something like this:
http://example.com/foo/bar.html

Then setup some suitable mod_rewrite rules on your server to redirect incoming links to the 'fake' url, back to your usual url.

Comment: just tried that and the send button resolves the URL first, gutting.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look here: https://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=10150231557835844 CTRL+F Some Limitations of the Send Button

Answer (score 0):

I do not completely understand your question but in facebook apps I use javascript to redirect the whole browser instead of just the iframe, use this:

```
<script>window.location.href="your url"</script>
```

return this as the body when you want to do a redirect.

Comment: Thanks for responding, but I'm not trying to create a link or redirect anywhere. I'm trying to use the Facebook Send plugin on my app tab. And I want the link that it sends to come straight back to the same tab, not just the root Facebook Page. Like this `<div class="fb-send" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/JBxOnline/254364851281976?sk=app_131026856999974"></div>`. However, when the user receives the link, they just get http://www.facebook.com/pages/JBxOnline/254364851281976. Does that make any more sense?

Answer (score 0):

Facebook Like, Recommend, and Send buttons will not allow you to link to a tab on a page. I ran into this problem myself, and found a workaround solution.

I used Facebook's share feature to create a share button or share link. When users click the link, they are taken to a page that links directly to the tab. They can select whether to share it on their own Facebook wall or in a private message.

Here's how:

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=URL_TO_FACEBOOK_PAGE_TAB" title="Share this with your friends!">Click here to share this with your friends!</a>
```

You can replace "Click here to share this with your friends" with an image if you would like. If you would like the link to open the share feature in a new window or tab, add target="_blank" to the parameters.

There's always a chance that Facebook might not support this style of share link forever...but this works for the time being.